# Results on the variance of the MAP estimate of the random effects in a GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, asymptotics

As part of a student project, I'm working on explaining this paper (link https://www.jstor.org/stable/43305585 ) "A simple test for random effects in regression models".  For context, it provides a way to test if a random effect is present by testing (in a LMM or GLMM) whether we can reject the null hypothesis that its variance is zero.
For this test, it's necessary to obtain the distribution of the random effects $b$ given the fixed effects, ie we need to know $f(b|\beta)$. In the LMM case, this is all derived in detail. I'm having trouble working out the GLMM case, where the author quickly states that the test still works, alluding to an asymptotic distribution of the MAP $b$. I'm only aware of the well-known asymptotic normal distribution of the MLE. In the GLMM case, the MAP estimate differs from the MLE. Is there a corresponding asymptotic distribution for MAPs?

I also have a (hopefully related) question:
If I have the large sample result (from "Generalized Additive Models", Simon Wood)
$$ \mathcal{B}|y\sim N(\hat{\mathcal{B}}, \Sigma)$$ for some matrix $\Sigma$ where $\mathcal{B}^T=(\beta^T,b^T)$ and $\hat{B}$ is the MAP estimate, is there a way to "invert" this result analytically to obtain the distribution of $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$ (in particular $\hat{b}$?)